# SQL Pivot function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Please help me to write a select query using to pivot my table as below

My table structure

[image]

And required result structure

> ### StoryLineID  PlotID StoryLine  Question
>
> ```
>  1          1      01      question 1
>  1          1      02      question 2
>  1          1      03      question 3
>  1          1      04      question 4
>  1          1      05      question 5
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      ID INT
    , PlotID INT
    , StoryLine_01 VARCHAR(10)
    , StoryLine_02 VARCHAR(10)
    , StoryLine_03 VARCHAR(10)
    , StoryLine_04 VARCHAR(10)
    , StoryLine_05 VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @temp
VALUES 
    (1, 3, 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5'),
    (2, 4, 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5')

SELECT 
      ID
    , PlotID
    , StoryLine = RIGHT(StoryLine, 2)
    , Question
FROM @temp
UNPIVOT 
(
    Question FOR StoryLine IN (
        StoryLine_01, StoryLine_02, 
        StoryLine_03, StoryLine_04, 
        StoryLine_05
    )
) unpvt
```

**Update (dynamic count of columns):**

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.temp') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.temp

CREATE TABLE dbo.temp
(
      ID INT
    , PlotID INT              , StoryLine_01 VARCHAR(10)
    , StoryLine_02 VARCHAR(10), StoryLine_03 VARCHAR(10)
    , StoryLine_04 VARCHAR(10), StoryLine_05 VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.temp
VALUES (1, 3, 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5'), (2, 4, 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5')

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = '
    SELECT 
          ID
        , PlotID
        , StoryLine = RIGHT(StoryLine, 2)
        , Question
    FROM dbo.temp
    UNPIVOT (
        Question FOR StoryLine IN (
            ' + STUFF((
                SELECT ', ' + name
                FROM sys.columns WITH(NOWAIT)
                WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.temp')
                    AND name LIKE 'StoryLine_%'
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + 
        ')
    ) unpvt'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Output -

```
ID          PlotID      StoryLine Question
----------- ----------- --------- ----------
1           3           01        Q1
1           3           02        Q2
1           3           03        Q3
1           3           04        Q4
1           3           05        Q5
2           4           01        Q1
2           4           02        Q2
2           4           03        Q3
2           4           04        Q4
2           4           05        Q5
```

Comment: :O Devart, nice to see native language, but I don't think it's fair to speak russian here :)

Answer (score 2):

if number of columns is large and number of total rows is not very large, you can do this general query, so you could not to specify all column name explicitly

```
;with CTE1 as (
    select ID, PlotID, (select t.* for xml raw('row'), type) as Data
    from @temp as t
), CTE2 as (
    select
         C.ID, C.PlotID,
         F.C.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') as StoryLine,
         F.C.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as Question
    from CTE1 as c
        outer apply c.Data.nodes('row/@*') as F(C)
)
select
   ID, PlotID, replace(StoryLine, 'StoryLine_', '') as StoryLine, Question
from CTE2
where StoryLine like 'StoryLine[_]%'
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18763) (Thanks @Devart!)